# ESP32 Flashing upload starts and fails with timeout

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, esp32, esp8266wifi

I have an ESP32-WROOM, [as seen here](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/356-ESP-WROOM-32).

In the Arduino IDE, I compile and verify my sketch, and then attempt an upload.

I get the following error:

```
esptool.py v2.1
Connecting........___
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision (unknown 0xa))
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Warning: Could not auto-detect Flash size (FlashID=0xffffff, SizeID=0xff), defaulting to 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content
A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content

Invalid library found in /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/libraries/BLE: no headers files (.h) found in /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/libraries/BLE
Invalid library found in /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/libraries/BLE: no headers files (.h) found in /Users/me/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/libraries/BLE
```

I am using these settings in the IDE for the upload:

[image]

I changed the baud rate to 115200, and then also watched the serial monitor, where i saw the following messages appear:

```
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0371 
⸮ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x23 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 37⸮ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x23 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x23 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 37ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x23 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
(SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
⸮ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x23 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

This is followed by:

esptool.py v2.1
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____An error occurred while uploading the sketch
_

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header on the Arduino IDE.

Please help me to understand what I need to do to make this sketch upload work direct to the ESP chip.

Comment: try lower baud rate

Comment: I changed it to 115200 but I get the same behaviour.

Comment: check the connections, try a different cable a different USB port

Comment: @RenegadeAndy did you solved this problem? Did you check the esp32 fuses? I have the same problem with an esp32 board and I suspect the fuses.

Answer (score 1):

One should need to **disconnect** the **Vin** pin until the code is successfully uploaded and keep pressing the **BOOT** button while uploading the sketch until the Connecting.. line disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the ESP32 automatically go into flash mode by connecting a 10uF electrolytic capacitor between EN and GND.
Make sure you observer the capacitor's polarity.
You can solder the capacitor onto the ESP32 board, as shown in the attached image.
[How to add an auto-enter-flash-mode capacitor on an ESP32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSAP.jpg)

Credit should go to
[Make ESP32 auto-enter flash mode](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/solved-failed-to-connect-to-esp32-timed-out-waiting-for-packet-header/)

Answer (score 0):

You want the 115200 baud setting.

I believe you are getting this error because the ESP32 is not in flash mode. Your computer is timing out waiting for the ESP32.

```
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____An error occurred while uploading the sketch _
```

Hold both the BOOT and EN, then release EN. If you have two button on your device, hold one and press the other. If that doesn't work then try the other hold/press button combination :)

Comment: I'm not sure, I get the DOWNLOAD_BOOT message and it says waiting for Download now when I watch the serial monitor. That to me says it is in the right boot mode. I am not using a dev board its just the esp32-wroom-32 direct

Comment: I'm not sure sorry. I moved away from the Arduino IDE and just went straight to [ESP-IDF](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/index.html#installation-step-by-step) using [Arduino-ESP](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) as a component. I'm not sure if that will help at all though.

Comment: Is that, the strategic way to work with the esp32 now?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy For any non-trivial project, I would recommend working via ESP-IDF and Arduino-ESP as a component. I have read similar suggestions on the ESP32 forum. There's a slight learning curve over the Arduino IDE but you gain a lot of control in return.

Comment: Alex is correct. If you're using one of the ESP32 Development boards, then you need an FTDI cable unless you want to manually manipulate the EN and IO0 lines yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem on custom board. According to datasheet to put ESP32 in download mode you need to have IO2(n24) and IO0(25) to 0, in my case i had some sensors connected to IO2 .
Also from datasheet:" * Pins SCK/CLK, SDO/SD0, SDI/SD1, SHD/SD2, SWP/SD3 and SCS/CMD, namely, GPIO6 to GPIO11 are connected
to the integrated SPI flash integrated on the module and are not recommended for other uses."

Answer (score 0):

Try to load without any connection. I did it and load well. I was connection one by one and the got error when I connect D12. I find a reference that tell load error if D12 was high. Then I put a resistor of 2K2 connecting D2 to ground end ESP32 load well.

Answer (score 0):

Put a 10uf capacitor on the EN line, with the + side on EN and the - side to ground.